# Cocos3D keyframe animation

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

I have a pod file that I am able to load into my cocos3d program. It was imported into blender in Windows XP and then directly exported to .pod format.  I am using blender 2.64

How can I get the embedded keyframe animations to play in cocos3d.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, If you want to run the animation 10 seconds and repeat forever on you object called playerNode:

```
CCActionInterval *stride = [CC3Animate actionWithDuration:10.0];
[playerNode runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:stride]];
```